# Consultar un campo segmentado

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo dos tablas la cual una esta creada a partir de los datos de los campos de la otra:

```
CREATE TABLE1(
CAMPO1 VARCHAR2(15),
CAMPO2 VARCHAR2(15),
CAMPO3 VARCHAR2(5),
CAMPO4 VARCHAR(20));

CREATE TABLE2(
CAMPO1 VARCHAR(20),
CAMPO2 VARCHAR(30));
```

Quiero insertar dentro de tabla2, la tabla 1 de la siguiente manera:

- tabla1.campo1 dentro de tabla2.campo1
- tabla1.campo2, tabla1.campo3 y tabla1.campo4 dentro de tabla2.campo2.

El problema es que tabla2.campo2 sólo acepta 30 carácteres (y no puedo modificar directamente con alter table el tamaño de éste campo ya que no puedo modificar la tabla) y quiero ponerle 40. He encontrado una manera de solucionar-lo y es con querys dinámicas:

```
querySql in varchar2;
queryInsert in varchar2;
queryValues in varchar2;
queryValuesTab1 in varchar2;
queryValuesTab2 in varchar2;

queryInsert := 'INSERT INTO TABLE2(campo1,campo2)';
queryValuesTab1 := 'SELECT campo1, campo2||campo3 from TABLE1';
queryValuesTab2 := 'SELECT campo1, campo4 from TABLE1';

v_num_reg in number := 1;
queryValues := queryValuesTab1;
querySql := queryInsert || ' ' || queryValues;
execute immediate querysql;
rc := sql%rowcount;

v_num_reg in number := 2;
queryValues := queryValuesTab2;
querySql := queryInsert || ' ' || queryValues;
execute immediate querysql;
rc := sql%rowcount;
```

Ahora el siguiente paso que querría realizar sería hacer una consulta a la tabla2. El problema está en que cuando se han introducido los datos en tabla2.campo2 estos se han introducido segmentados. Cómo puedo recuperar todos estos datos (los 40 carácteres) y no sólo los 30 carácteres que acepta tabla2.campo2?

Muchas grácias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente, no había necesidad de usar queries dinámicas. Los inserts que hicistes equivalen a ejecutar las 2 sentencias siguientes:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2(campo1,campo2)
SELECT campo1, campo2||campo3 from TABLE1;

INSERT INTO TABLE2(campo1,campo2)
SELECT campo1, campo4 from TABLE1;
```

Ahora bien, el problema es que cuando dices que los datos están segmentados, lo que quieres decir es que has creado 2 registros en la tabla `TABLE2` por cada registro en la tabla `TABLE1`.

Y aunque es *posible* juntar los 2 registros usando `campo1` como referencia para poder reconstruir `campo2` con los 40 caracteres, la consulta va a ser sumamente frágil, por al menos las 2 razones siguientes:

- No hay manera de determinar el orden de los 2 registros para poder juntar `campo2||campo3` antes de `campo4`.
- No hay garantía que solo 2 registros compartan el mismo valor para `campo1`.

Si no te importan estos problemas, puedes usar la consulta siguiente:

```
select campo1, min(campo2) || max(campo2) as campo2
  from table2
 group by campo1
```

... pero no te sorprendas si los valores no salen 100% como los esperas.

La verdad es que lo que estás haciendo al segmentar los datos parece una muy mala idea de la que te vas a arrepentir luego. Lo mejor es modificar tus tablas para acomodar los datos que necesitas de la manera correcta. Yo sé que dijistes:

> y no puedo modificar directamente con alter table el tamaño de éste campo ya que no puedo modificar la tabla

Pero lo cierto es que siempre hay una manera de hacerlo si hablas con la persona correcta que tiene el acceso y si le explicas porqué lo necesitas.

**Nota adicional**

Veo que la definición de tus tablas usa una mezcla de los tipos `varchar` y `varchar2`. En Oracle, es recomendable que favorezcas el tipo `varchar2`.

Answer (score 0):

Si no quieres solicitar que se altere la tabla, lo cual se me hace una sandez, en fin.
Observando el ejemplo de estructura de las tablas supongo que en cada una de ellas el campo1 es un id el cual en la tabla1 es de 15 y en la tabla2 es de 20, lo que tienes que hacer es una fumada pero te funcionara. Saludos; espero te sirva.

`...
queryInsert := 'INSERT INTO TABLE2(campo1,campo2)';
queryValuesTab1 := 'SELECT TRIM(campo1)||00001, campo2||campo3 from TABLE1';
queryValuesTab2 := 'SELECT TRIM(campo1)||00002, campo4 from TABLE1';
...`